# Jasmine Error: Expected spy decode to have been called with [ [ ] ] but actual calls were [ undefined ]

Tags: javascript, extjs, jasmine

I'm trying to learn Ext JS and unit testing with Jasmine framework. I wrote this method and I want to test if `decode` method is being called with a certain value, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the caption. What am I doing wrong here?

The method:

```
onSuccess: function (response) {
    var text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    this.someGrid.store.loadRawData(text);
}
```

Jasmine spec:

```
it('Function will call decode method', function () {
    var response = {};
    spyOn(Ext, 'decode').and.returnValue([]);
    me.testObj.onSuccess(response);
    expect(Ext.decode).toHaveBeenCalledWith([]);
})
```

Comment: I don't think this test is particularly useful. That's more testing the internals of the framework. You would be better off testing that the data that's in the store matches what you think it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in an empty object to the function **Ext.decode()** and therefore when the function tries to access the **responseText** property it receives undefined.

```
// var response = {}; - empty object created in your test
Ext.decode(response.responseText);
```

In your onSuccess function the call to **returnValue()** will return the empty array - as set up in your spy. And this empty array will be stored in the text variable. It will then be passed to the **loadRawData()** function, and not **decode()**, as your spy currently expects.

```
var text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
this.someGrid.store.loadRawData(text);
```

In order to correctly test the function you could mock the response object in your test to contain a **responseText** property. And you could also add spy and expect statements for the **loadRawData()** function, something like the following:

```
it('Function will call decode method', function () {
    // mock response object has responseText propety
    var response = { responseText: 'mockResponseText' };
    spyOn(Ext, 'decode').and.returnValue([]);
    // spy to LoadRawData added to check return value of decode is passed on correctly
    spyOn(me.testObj.someGrid.store, 'loadRawData');

    me.testObj.onSuccess(response);

    // Ext.decode should be called with the response text
    expect(Ext.decode).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mockResponseText');
    // loadRawData should be called with return value of decode function
    expect(me.testObj.someGrid.store.loadRawData).toHaveBeenCalledWith([]);
})
```